# Is "incidence of illnesses" correct phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

In this sentence, is "incidence of illnesses" natural and meaningful? I wanted to mean the number of cases where people get sick.

> The higher incidence of illnesses might significantly reduce the
> attendance rate.

I think it is a bit wordy. Is the following a better version?

> Higher illnesses might significantly reduce the
> attendance rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Incidence" looks reasonable.  You shouldn't just say "Higher illnesses", as that sounds like you are trying to talk about how bad each illness is, and not how many there are.

You should be aware of a *technical* difference between incidence and prevalence.

> Prevalence = the ***number of cases*** of a disease in a specific population ***at a particular timepoint*** or over a specified period of time.
>
> ...
>
> Incidence = the ***rate of new cases*** of a disease occurring in a specific population over a particular period of time.
>
> ...
>
> Prevalence differs from incidence proportion as prevalence includes all cases (new and pre-existing cases) in the population at the specified time whereas incidence is limited to new cases only.

[Prevalence vs. Incidence: what is the difference?](https://s4be.cochrane.org/blog/2020/11/06/prevalence-vs-incidence-what-is-the-difference/) explains further.